# How is a true or false result determined if a struct or a pointer is used as the parameter to an if statement in C?

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, struct

I've been reading other people's code, but the parameters people use to  if statements are really confusing to me. I've seen people place pointers and structs as parameters, but I don't understand how it's decided whether the result of the logical statement will be true or false. For example:

```
 struct Foo foo;

if(foo)
doSomething();

char *ch = malloc(sizeof(char));

if(num)
doSomethingElse();
```

If someone were to write and compile this, how would a true of false result be determined from the logical statements in the if statements?

Comment: In c, 0 is considered false and everything else is considered true.

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Nothing can be said. `foo` is not initialized.

Comment: It's not legal C.  You can't use a struct value in a scalar context.  This won't compile.

Comment: @SouravGhosh incorrect, `if (foo)` gives a compilation error.

Comment: @TomKarzes and i thought foo as a pointer. I blame the title/ :(

Comment: It's what happens when people post code without even trying to compile it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer is usable as a boolean value.  A null pointer is considered false, and a non-null pointer is considered true.

Numbers are usable as a boolean value.  A zero-valued number is considered false, and any other value is considered true.

Structs are not usable as boolean values, although a pointer to a struct is.

Comment: C doesn't have classes.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Yep, my mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The controlling expression of a `if` statement cannot be of an aggregate type (e.g., a structure type), it can only be of scalar type (e.g., integer type, pointer type, ...).

```
struct Foo foo;
if (foo)          // not valid, foo is of a structure type

if (&foo)         // valid, &foo is of a pointer type 

if ((void *) 0)  // valid, (void *) 0 is of a pointer type

if (42)          // valid, 42 is of an integer type

if (3.14159)     // valid, 3.14159 is of a floating point type
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, if an expression needs to be interpreted as a truth value, it is compared to `0`, with the normal conversions being applied as needed.  In the case of integers, it's obvious.  In the case of a floating point value, the `0` is converted to `0.0`.  In the case of a pointer, the pointer is compared to the null pointer.  In the case of a struct or a union, the comparison is meaningless and a compile-time error is given.